# Why is the frequency of emitted photon of laser different from the frequency of incident photon?

Tags: laser, laser-interaction

Why is the frequency of photons emitted from a laser different than the frequency of the incident photon?

Comment: Reference(s), please--

Comment: Can you give us more detail?  Why do you think photons of two frequencies are needed?  Are you instead asking why the pump photons have a higher frequency than the photons emitted by the laser?

Comment: @garyp: Yes, exactly why there is frequency difference of incident and emitted photon of laser?

Answer (score 2):

To have lasing action one needs a population inversion: given two energy levels , to keep most of  the electrons at the higher level is not possible  if there is only one frequency from the deexcitation.

> As described above, [a population inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion#Creating_a_population_inversion) is required for laser operation, but cannot be achieved in our theoretical group of atoms with two energy-levels when they are in thermal equilibrium. In fact, any method by which the atoms are directly and continuously excited from the ground state to the excited state (such as optical absorption) will eventually reach equilibrium with the de-exciting processes of spontaneous and stimulated emission. At best, an equal population of the two states, N1 = N2 = N/2, can be achieved, resulting in optical transparency but no net optical gain.

> To achieve non-equilibrium conditions, an indirect method of populating the excited state must be used. To understand how this is done, we may use a slightly more realistic model, that of a three-level laser

Read on the link .